# What Means the Final Option in Bump Fee / Increase Fee Electrum Wallet Option

Tags: transaction-fees, electrum, fee-estimation, bumpfee

Hello I want to know what will happen if i put my transaction as Final can saves fee or no?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting `final` will disable RBF for the transaction and you will not be increase the fee anymore.

Example: I did a transaction [7d1a7ecd1a68443c07f89f38180d3f3dc945edb2784ebfb7f7c113842d7d8509](https://tbtc.bitaps.com/7d1a7ecd1a68443c07f89f38180d3f3dc945edb2784ebfb7f7c113842d7d8509) with fee rate 1 sat/vByte, increased the fee rate to 3 sat/vBbyte and replace the transaction with [d47e59db69c91f3e653da9c5ed0e0f9fc8fdc4422a4e8650d4d6b66c1db60f18](https://tbtc.bitaps.com/d47e59db69c91f3e653da9c5ed0e0f9fc8fdc4422a4e8650d4d6b66c1db60f18) and increased the fee rate again to 5 sat/vByte but selected `final` this time so RBF was disabled for this transaction [2a7241f60d301ccda31a7be875d58610637534fe477e8c76d0e67bc31ef5824f](https://tbtc.bitaps.com/2a7241f60d301ccda31a7be875d58610637534fe477e8c76d0e67bc31ef5824f)

Cannot increase the fee rate anymore using RBF because it was disabled. Either I can wait for it to get confirmed or use CPFP.

[image: RBF:FALSE]

Comment: what is the utility of this option? i did a transaction months ago with 7 sat/vByte and took 1.5 months for confirm. if i can't not increase my fee i see very serious problems.

Comment: You can still increase fee by CPFP for many transactions which is a workaround. Option to disable RBF for a transaction is good although I am not sure about usecase. It is unchecked by default.